# I think I have discovered a proof for the irrationality of $\sqrt{2}$, but I'm not sure

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm not a mathematician/mathematics student/amateur mathematician.  I'm just some guy preparing for a GMAT-type exam. I couldn't sleep last night as I was lost in thought on bed and this proof came to me. I'm not claiming this to be a "new" proof; maybe it's already well known. But I've had my fair share of disappointments in the past when I thought I had "discovered" something, when all it was was really just a poor understanding of the problem and related elements.

Please help me understand if this proof for the irrationality of $\sqrt{2}$ is correct.

*Proof*:

A necessary condition to form a Pythagorean triplet is that, *in its simplest form*, **one (and only one)** of the two smaller integers of the triplet should be divisible by $4$.  (I hope this is obvious, but I can provide clarification for this if needed - edit: this condition seems to be generating confusion, so I've added an easy-to-visualize example below).

Assuming that $\sqrt{2}$ is rational violates this condition in the following way:

If $\sqrt 2= a/b$ with $a,b\in \mathbb Z$,
then $2b^2=a^2$.

This gives rise to $b^2+b^2=a^2$, a Pythagorean triplet in $(b,b,a), b<a$.

This indicates that either **both** the smaller numbers of the triplet are divisible by $4$, or that **neither** is. Either of these outcomes violates the condition for forming a Pythagorean triplet, invaldiating the assumption that $\sqrt{2}$ is rational.

Edit:  Example for the Pythagorean condition below.  This isn't a rigorous/formal proof, just an intuitive one.  The beads of the blue square must "encircle" the red square, which is the only way the aggregate of the two can form the larger square.  Since the red square has four sides, the blue square must necessarily contain a number of beads which is divisible by $4$.

[image: 3 squared plus 4 squared equals 5 squared]

Comment: Only one and only one being divisible by 4 is not quite true, for example there is 12, 16, 20.

Comment: @Paul That's not in it's simplest form, it's similar to $(3, 4, 5)$ with scaling factor 4.

Comment: But that triplet is NOT in its simplest form.  All 3 are divisible by 4, leaving 3, 4, and 5. Only one of these 3 is divisible by 4.

Comment: Ah, fair enough.  I misunderstood the simplest form phrase.

Comment: I think the proof of the Pythagorean fact is likely to use (at least implicitly) that an even square is divisible by $4$.

Comment: @AkashC I am not sure whether this proof is easier than the usual way. Perhaps, you like the following proof : Like usual, we assume that we have positive integers $a,b$ with $\sqrt{2}=\frac{a}{b}$, so $a^2=2b^2$. Now consider the prime factorizations of the numbers $a^2$ and $2b^2$. Considering only the exponent belonging to prime number $2$ (In the case of an odd number, this exponent is $0$), we see that it must be even for $a^2$ and odd for $2b^2$, hence $a^2$ and $2b^2$ cannot be the same numbers. We do not even need that $a$ and $b$ are coprime.

Comment: @Peter - I am aware of that proof, too. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Please do not remove the content of your question, especially after it has been answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an addition to John Hughes answer that proves the necessary condition. Since $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$, if $c$ is odd we have that at least one of $a, b$ must be even, and thus at least one of $a^2$, $b^2$ divisible by 4. That part is easy.

On the other hand if $c^2$ is even both $a$ and $b$ can be odd, and without ruling this possibility out for a primitive $(a, b, c)$ the proof is not complete. It should be obvious that if $a$, $b$ are both even the triplet wasn't primitive.

There is a way to complete your proof. Consider the equation $\bmod 4$, with $a, b$ both odd:

$$a^2 + b^2 \equiv c^2 \mod 4$$

Regardless if $a \equiv 1$ or $a\equiv 3 \mod 4$, since $3^2 \equiv 1 \mod 4$ we have:

$$1 + 1 \equiv c^2 \mod 4$$

But $c$ is even, thus

$$2 \equiv 0 \mod 4$$

which shows there are no solutions, thus $a, b$ can't both be odd with even $c$.

Comment: "On the other hand if $c^2$ is even both $a$ and $b$ can be odd" - both $a$ and $b$ can never be odd.  The condition becomes easy to visualize if you think of these whole numbers in terms of beads, and their squares being represented by geometric squares.  One of them must necessarily be divisible by 4 in order to "encircle" the other along its $4$ sides, and thus must be divisible by 4. I'll add a diagram to my answer.

Comment: @AkashC I just showed one way of proving that it isn't possible in this answer. Your proof isn't formal enough (for my taste), for example beads necklaces of length $3$ and $5$ can encircle a square of side length $2$. Now, $3$ and $5$ aren't odd squares themselves, but without modular arithmetic it's hard to prove that it's never possible with odd squares.

Comment: I'm sorry, I had misread your answer.  Yours is a more formal proof, I now get it.  Thanks for the clarification :) (I feel silly for not seeing it, forgive me. I'm not a trained mathematician).

Answer (score 4):

That's a correct proof, assuming that you've proved your "necessary condition". The proof of that necessary condition, however, may be just as complex as the more traditional proofs that $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational.

The "only one" part is easy, for if both small numbers are divisible by 4, then the large number is too, and it's not "in simplest form". The "one" part is less obvious (at least to me, at this moment, before I've had that first shot of caffeine).

Comment: Since $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$, if $c$ is odd we have that at least one of $a, b$ must be even, and thus at least one of $a^2$, $b^2$ divisible by 4. That part is easy. On the other hand if $c^2$ is even both $a$ and $b$ can be odd, and without ruling this possibility out for a primitive $(a, b, c)$ the proof is not complete.

Comment: The "at least one" part should be true because, since all three are whole numbers (imagine discrete beads representing each of the numbers), and since you are squaring every single one of the numbers in the triplet, one of the two smaller squares of beads should be dismantled and made to encircle the other square along its perimeter. (Doing this is the only way of getting the third, bigger square) Since the perimeter of a square has four sides to it, the square that is being dismantled must necessarily be divisible by 4 in order to encircle the other square *completely*.

Comment: See my answer for a proof of the remaining necessary condition.